# Wondering how I might be able to debug this ACL issue

Tags: lotus-notes

I'm adding security around some buttons in an app I built long ago.  The way I implemented this security feature is that I created a a role in the database's ACL.  I do a check in the button's hide-when formula and expose the button if the role is there. That role is assigned to a security group in the Domino Directory.  That security group contains a collection of other groups.  These 2ndary groups contain people's names.  Those names are retrieved from a Postgres database -- I have a LotusScript agent that pulls the names from that database.  The problem I'm seeing is that even tho a name is in the 2ndary group, Notes doesn't recognize it. Here's an example.  This user are in these groups:
[image]

however, he should also be in all of these:
[image]

How can I debug where the problem is?

thanks
clem

Comment: Ummm... I'm not seeing a difference in the two lists of groups.

Comment: How many users is your agent adding to the secondary groups? (It's not actually the number of users that matters; it's the size of the data in the members field. It needs to stay within the summary buffer limits. The number of users is just a good first check.)

Comment: opps... uploaded the wrong 2nd image.

Comment: At the most, there might be 25 people in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that for one group in particular, there are 2 copies of the group document.  I didn't see that b/c in the main group view it doesn't show up.  But when I was in the process of assigning a child group to a parent group, I can see the duplicate listed.  I suspect this is the source of the problem.  Will confirm.

thanks
clem

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the members of the 2ndary groups contain names in fully qualified format that matches the first entry of their FullName in the person document. EG "John Smith" should be "CN=John Smith/O=LabWare" or something like that.

You can see what groups and roles the system recognizes a user in by double clicking on the security icon on the status bar in the Notes Client (bottom 3rd from the right) after you have opened the database.

Comment: Thanks, good tip about the security icon.  I used it from my own account and it confirms the problem -- despite the fact that I'm in several security groups which are assigned to different roles, I don't have those roles.  I even added a computed-on-display field to show all the roles a user has and when I open the document, the roles are missing.  The problem is that it works fine for other people in the same group!  I haven't been able to figure out why one person gets the roles while another does not.